# I'm getting a code error in a weird place, and when I try and fix it, I get lots of errors. How can I fix it?

Tags: java

I'm writing a program called SalesTax.java. The program will create an output that tells the sales tax on a $50 purchase, when the sales tax changes depending on the day in the month of January. I like to save my program and run it often, so I can see that I got that section right. When I run the stuff I have done, I get a super weird error and I have no idea what I'm doing wrong.

I've tried to create the syntax the compile message error told me, where I get more errors: `SalesTax.java:6: error: variable N is already defined in method main(String[])`     and
 `SalesTax.java:6: error: lambda expression not expected here.`

```
public class SalesTax {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      int N = 1;
      int Item = 50;
      int st = N;
      System.out.println("On January " + (N)", The Sales Tax will be " + (st / 100) * Item);
   }
}
```

I expect the output to be: On January 1, The Sales Tax will be 50.5. However, instead I'm getting this:

```
SalesTax.java:6: error: cannot find symbol
      System.out.println("On January " + (N)", The Sales Tax will be " + (st / 100) * Item);
                                          ^
  symbol:   class N
  location: class SalesTax
1 error
```

Any ideas on how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a `+` after `(N)` to concatenate it with the next string:

```
System.out.println("On January " + (N) + ", The Sales Tax will be " + (st / 100) * Item);
```

Answer (score 1):

You forgot a plus after (N). Try:

```
System.out.println("On January " + N + ", The Sales Tax will be " + (st / 100) * Item);
```

also note that in java, 1 / 100 (st is 1, so, that's what `(st / 100)` ends up being) is straight up 0, and not 0.01; integer math just rounds. If you want floating point stuff, you need `double` and not `int`. So, try: `double st = N;` instead.

Comment: or `st / 100.00`